Unexpected return from initial read: Device error, buffersize 0
After updating GRUB I get:
Unexpected return from initial read: Device error, buffersize 0
Failed to load image: Device error
start_image() returned Device error

My first guess is that the disk is broken. But booting from a LiveUSB I can read the first 10 GB with no errors. Also the disk is ~1 yr old SSD not under heavy load: It is not dead from wear.
Is there a way to fix this?
Fresh Ubuntu 24.04, LUKS on /dev/sda3
Lenovo T420
Edit
Moving the SSD to USB: Warm reboot OK.
Moving the SSD to CD-caddy: Same as if in HDD-slot: Warm reboot fails.
Booting on USB with Debian 5.0: Warm reboot to USB: OK. Warm reboot to SSD: OK - but only first time. 2nd warm reboot to SSD fails!
Changing BIOS from UEFI=Both to either UEFI-only or Legacy-only would cause either USB-boot or SSD-boot to fail and would not fix warm reboot from SSD to SSD.
Copying SSD to HDD works! Warm boot from internal HDD to internal HDD works!?!
So something is not resat correctly when rebooting from internal SSD to internal SSD.
This trick does not work: Boot from USB - redirect to SSD
Possible (but untested) workaround: Move /boot from SSD to HDD-2 or USB.
Also test: Is this due to SSD? Will another SSD give same problem?

If you suspect the disk is failing, you should use smartctl -a to check for errors or other end of life conditions.
From your edited question, it sounds like the SSD's controller is crashing and not recovering without a cold reset, which might happen on USB under some conditions even on a warm boot.
This could be a firmware bug in the SSD or it could be a controller failure or even failing media.  The smartctl utility might be helpful in checking drive internal logs, assuming the causing event is logged at all.

I do not: The disk is 1 year old and not under heavy load. As you can see https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/776814/2972 cold boot works every time. This is more likely caused by some state not being properly resat when warm booting.

Have you actually checked the output of smartctl on this drive?

Can you justify why I should do that? There are 0 bad sectors when booting. It performs with no problems what so ever except for warm rebooting. It can even warm reboot correctly when connected to USB. What smartctl error would you think could cause a warm reboot to fail - but only in the internal slot?

Can you justify why you shouldn't check smartctl -a?  It's a fully passive operation.   Drives almost never have 0 bad blocks, but they get replaced. Typically drives operate with no problems until they accumulate enough bad blocks to run out of replacements, at which point they fail completely and suddenly.  You can use smartctl to check if there have been recent errors or accumulating bad blocks.  If it matters what slot it is in, maybe you have a failing slot.

Warm reboot could fail if the drive hits a flaw bad enough to cause it to go offline, and then a warm boot isn't sufficient to reset it.

This applies to spinning disks and SSDs, but differently.  SSDs do wear leveling, which hides bad blocks better.  But you also can have controller failures, and both ssd and spinning disks can get brown outs on bad slots that cause them to go offline.

Saying "my drive can't be wearing out, it still works" is like saying "my pen can't be running out of ink, it's been writing for years"

I run into the same situation.
HW: Lenovo Laptop W520, 4TB SSD, Fedora 40.
The solution:

BIOS update to version 1.46.
Files from Lenovo web site: 8buj25uc.txt  8buj25us.iso

journalctl records that gave the clue:
Nov 22 23:34:11 joyw520 kernel: DMAR: [Firmware Bug]: No firmware reserved region can cover this RMRR [0x00000000bb800000-0x00000000bf9fffff], contact BIOS vendor for fixes
Nov 22 23:34:11 joyw520 kernel: DMAR: [Firmware Bug]: Your BIOS is broken; bad RMRR [0x00000000bb800000-0x00000000bf9fffff]
BIOS vendor: LENOVO; Ver: 8BET61WW (1.41 ); Product Version: ThinkPad W520


Work around: Power-off and power-on.
Every cold boot works. The problem is only at warm boot/reboot.
Todo: Test if this is Ubuntu only. Try with other Live USBs to see if they work. The hardware is old (except for the disk), so test if old Live USBs work. Test if this is caused by SSD. Will rotating disk work?

Same issue with the same computer. Wanted to upgrade it with a new SSD and 16 Go RAM, but mine is in classic ext FS, not crypted. Same observation, cold boot OK, reboot KO.
Is it the BIOS ? Grub ? The Ubuntu OS ? I am waiting to see if some updates correct it, but I am starting to think that the hardware is starting to become obsolete.

This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking Ask Question. To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can follow this question. Once you have enough reputation, you can also add a bounty to draw more attention to this question. - From Review
